# Highstock range approximation on spline series

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use Highstock to draw 10 seconds of an ECG signal sampled at 250Hz, that is, 2500 points. The problem I have is due to data grouping approximation, and the fact that each value of the signal can vary widely from its neighbors in some cases, so any of the approximation functions provided by Highstock result in a very distorted signal after drawing, because the maximums and the minimums are lost in most cases. I created a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/YaubF/) showing the effect. Just drag the signal to make groups being recalculated and look at the peaks of the beats.

One solution to this problem is to use a range approximation function that represents each group with two points (minimum and maximum), but i think there is currently no available option in Highstock to do this on spline series. Even if you provide your own approximation function, you have to return one single point as a result.

I think it should be possible to implement this by **providing my own approximation function which returns min and max**, and **modifying `seriesProto.groupData` function where the grouping and approximation are applied to properly manage this result**.

Looking at the code I really don't know how to do that.

**EDIT:**

As Pawel points out in the first answer, an arearange series could be an option to preserve minimuns and maximuns. Even so, I need to draw only a line or spline, not an area range with time points with two diferent values on the y axis. Then, the question that arises is: **would be possible to edit the way arearange series are drawn to obtain one single line or spline with all data?** If possible, where I should look/touch in the sources?

Comment: If you put the approximation parameter on "high", you can get a pretty steady chart, but I'm not sure if its precise enough for you.  
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.spline.dataGrouping.approximation

Comment: What you say is true for the data I have put in the example, but with other series with picks down not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it in a fairly simple way. Since the solution of the problem was basically to represent each group with two points (maximum and minimum), I ended up implementing a custom approximation function that returns the result delayed by a point. That is, I wait until I have two sets of points to approximate, and then I calculate the minimum and maximum with all of them. Finally I return the first of them and keep the other to return in the next iteration. Here is the function code:

```
approximation: function (arr) {
    // first time or point precalculated          
    if (!gInfo || gInfo.nextPoint) {
        // first time return first value (arr[0])
        var point = gInfo ? gInfo.nextPoint : arr[0];
        // save current data to the next iteration    
        gInfo = {
            prev: arr,
            nextPoint: null
        };
        return point;
    } else {
        var prev = gInfo.prev,
            // concat current group with the previous one
            data = prev.concat(arr),
            // get min, max and their positions        
            min = Math.min.apply(null, data),
            max = Math.max.apply(null, data),
            minIdx = data.indexOf(min),
            maxIdx = data.indexOf(max),
            // order min and max
            aprox = minIdx < maxIdx ? [min, max] : [max, min];
        // save next aproximation and return current
        gInfo.nextPoint = aprox[1];
        return aprox[0];
    }
}
```

I also set the option `groupPixelWidth: .5` to allow the creation of more groups, and these approximate a smaller number of points.

Here is a live example of this approach  http://jsfiddle.net/zw7D8/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply change series type to arearange, where default values are the same. I have upgraded example:

- change data format:

  ```
  var data = getData();

  for(var i in data) {
      data[i] = [i, data[i], data[i]];   
  }
  ```
- set different series type:

  ```
  series: [{
      type: 'arearange',
      pointInterval: 4, // 250Hz
      data: data,
      dataGrouping: {
          enabled: true
      },
      enabled: true
  }]
  ```

  And live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xzcwB/

Comment: I think this solution could be acceptable in the flatter parts of the signal and in the peaks because now at least the minimum and maximum are preserved, but the folds are still quite distorted. May be a bit of tweaking in the arearange plotoptions might produce a better result, but I think it is not going to be precise enought.

Comment: If that solution won't work for you, then indeed, you need to edit sources.